Утечка памяти массива char**?
Делаю проект в котором с недавнего времени добавлена функция логирования действий программы на случай натыкания на баг или вылет что поможет ускорить поиск проблемы. Логер представляет из себя синглет класс, который можно дёрнуть из любого участка программы и сделано это для удобства. Логер представляет собой простенький класс, содержащий указатель на указатели, из которого создаётся массив логов типа char, счётчик количества логов и поле в которое пользователь может задать предел количества создаваемых логов по достижению которого массив логов чистится и указатель пересоздаётся. В объявлении я не указал методы и поля связанные с синглетом так как считаю что там всё нормально, синглет я создавал по материалам отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/how-do-you-implement-the-singleton-design-pattern
logger_backend.h
class logger_backend
{
    private:
        char** log_container; //Массив сообщений логов
        uint32_t log_str_counter; //Счётчик количества логов
        uint32_t msg_limit; //Ограничение, задаваемое юзером - по умолчанию 16384
    public:
        logger_backend();
        ~logger_backend(); //Перед выходом нужно прибраться за собой
        void insert_log(const char* log, uint32_t log_size); //Метод копирует строчку логов в массив сообщений и увеличивает его размер на 1 строчку
        void clear_logs(); //Чистка логов
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ метод, который вызывает у меня вопрос
        uint32_t get_size(); //return log_str_counter;
        uint32_t get_limit(); //return msg_limit;
        void set_limit(uint32_t limit); //msg_limit = limit;
};

Конструктор класса, в котором поле log_container инициализируется как массив размером в 1 пустую строчку
logger_backend::logger_backend()
{
    log_str_counter = 0;    //Выделяем память на один указатель больше, на всякий
    log_container = (char**)calloc(log_str_counter + 1, sizeof(char*));
    msg_limit = 0;  //По умолчанию параметр не задан, позже будет из программы однократно вызван метод который задаст предел 16384, но гарантированно не позже первого вызова insert_log. 
}

Метод, который копирует лог в массив. При вызове создаются два временных указателя, которые нужны для проверки на успешность функций calloc и realloc и затем создаёт строчку лога добавляя в начало значение таймера для лучшего восприятия хронологии событий
void logger_backend::insert_log(const char* log, uint32_t log_size)
{
    char** new_lc_ptr;  //Указатель на новый блок, для проверки на валидность
    char* new_l_ptr;        //То же самое но для строчки

    //Выделяем память для указателя на строчку логов
    ++log_str_counter; //Здесь идёт перевыделение памяти для указателя char* с приростом на одну строчку
    new_lc_ptr = (char**)realloc(log_container, sizeof(char*)*log_str_counter);
    if (new_lc_ptr != NULL)
    {
        log_container = new_lc_ptr;
        //Выделяем память для занесения строчки логов
        new_l_ptr = (char*)calloc(16 + log_size + 2, sizeof(char));
        if (new_l_ptr != NULL) //Проверка, если calloc не смог выделить то он вернёт NULL
        { //Слепляем строчку лога, которая должна выглядеть вот так: [03:49:21.18435]Какой_то_лог из аргумента log
            log_container[log_str_counter - 1] = new_l_ptr;
            log_container[log_str_counter - 1][0] = '[';
            //Достаём значение системного таймера
            strncpy(&log_container[log_str_counter - 1][1], &boost::posix_time::to_iso_extended_string(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()).c_str()[11], 14);
            log_container[log_str_counter - 1][15] = ']';
            strncpy(&log_container[log_str_counter - 1][16], log, log_size);
            log_container[log_str_counter - 1][log_size + 16] = '\0';
        }
        else
            throw(exceptionHandler(exceptionHandler::WARNING, "Не удалось выделить память для строчки лога"));
    }
    else
        throw(exceptionHandler(exceptionHandler::WARNING, "Не удалось создать строчку логов"));
}

И теперь перейду к методу, который вызывает у меня вопрос. Метод вызывается если значение log_str_counter равно или больше msg_limit и сначала чистит строки, приравнивает их к NULL и затем уже чистит сам указатель и пересоздаёт его. Данный способ я заимствовал отсюда https://www.w3schools.com/c/c_memory_deallocate.php
void logger_backend::clear_logs()
{
    //Чистим строки
    for (uint32_t _index = 0; _index < log_str_counter; ++_index)
    {
        free(log_container[_index]); //указатель чистится
        log_container[_index] = NULL; //Указатель становится пустым
    }
    free(log_container);    //Чистим массив и пересоздаём указатель
    log_container = NULL; //аналогичная схема
    log_str_counter = 0;
    log_container = (char**)calloc(log_str_counter + 1, sizeof(char*)); //Указатель пересоздаётся и в нём оставляется одна пустая строчка, которая затем будет использована снова
}

Но так как в разных частях программы от логера нужно выполнение различных задач, то на этот класс написана "обёртка" из двух функций
void push_log(const char* log)  //По идее это должно без проблем вызываться из сишных файлов
{
    t_mut.lock();   //Эта тема будет вызываться из разных потоков поэтому надо выстроить очередь
    if (logger_backend::getInstance().get_limit() != 0) //Предел задан то тогда проверяем достигнут ли
    {                                                   //если достигнут то чистим говнище вилкой
        if (logger_backend::getInstance().get_size() == logger_backend::getInstance().get_limit())
        {
            //С 0.2.8 теперь дампится по пути заданному в конфиге каждый раз по достижению лимита
            save_log(); //Сохраняет лог в файл
            logger_backend::getInstance().clear_logs();
        }
    }
    logger_backend::getInstance().insert_log(log, strlen(log));
    t_mut.unlock();
}

И вторая функция представляет собой перегруженную для работы со string push_log
void push_log(const std::string& log)
<...>
logger_backend::getInstance().insert_log(log.c_str(), log.size());

Код, который сохраняет лог в файл
    std::string logPath = QString(getConfigPath()).toStdString() + '/' + filename;
    std::ofstream log(logPath);
    for (uint32_t _index = 0; _index < logger_backend::getInstance().get_size(); ++_index)
    {
        filename = QString::fromUtf8(logger_backend::getInstance().get_stroke(_index)).toStdString() + '\n'; //Если не использовать преобразование из utf8 то логи превращаются в абрукадабру в файле
        stable_log.write(filename.c_str(), filename.size()); 
    }
    log.close();

И то же самое для QString. Так как логер потом нужно будет прилепить к другому проекту на C(и класс переписать на некое его подобие по примеру https://habr.com/ru/articles/568588/), от malloc, calloc, realloc и free я не могу избавиться в пользу более хороших new/delete и умных указателей
Сам метод, при компиляции с пресетом Release в visual studio 2019 работает без нареканий, не критует, в логах абракадабры и прочей аномальщины не видно. Я тестировал с закидыванием около 500 тысяч сообщений и всё работает прекрасно. Но вот что напрягает - вижла регистрирует утечку памяти после каждого вызова чистки логов хотя я был уверен что чистка проходит как надо и без нареканий. Банальное наблюдение из диспетчера задач тоже показывает странность. Просмотр состояния кучи после каждой чистки показывает следующее: При достижении значения в 16384, вызывается метод clear_logs() и я делаю снимок кучи перед его выполнением и после. Я замечаю что размер занимаемой памяти незначительно уменьшается - то есть что-то и правда чистится и удаляется, но при этом порождается куча void, и остаётся большое количество char - прирост каждый цикл хотя ожидается снижение размера занимаемой памяти так как я чищу память используя free и принуляю указатель. Откуда берутся void и как мне лучше чистить char? У меня также есть предположение, что мои манипуляции с указателями в insert_log порождают после себя "брошенные" указатели, которые остаются в памяти программы и копятся там. Использование free на обоих - free(new_lc_ptr) и free(new_l_ptr) вызывает срабатывание исключения хотя они уже считаются отработанными и не должны провоцировать это

Я посмотрел дюжину подобных тем на английском so, насколько хватило знаний сформировать правильный запрос но решения либо не подходили под мой случай, либо их эффективность была сомнительной. Возникает вопрос - не провоцируют ли утечку сишные функции работы с памятью, нужно ли мне всё таки перейти на new/delete и умные указатели, и как мне поступать с двумя указателями, которыми я оперирую в методе insert_log?
UPD Я проверил возможную причастность самого класса в утечке, но он чист

Как можно проверить гарантированное уничтожение аргумента char* после его передачи? И не может ли std::string провоцировать утечку?

Его нету в языке С, подразумевается что этот логер потом будет переделан на чистый си и превращать его полностью в плюсовый не самая лучшая идея, хотя если все варианты будут исчерпаны то я массив указателей заменю на вектор и тогда для приложения на С придумаю что-нибудь другое

Если в конструкторе сделать по вашей рекомендации: log_str_counter = 0, log_containter = NULL то класс отрабатывает без нареканий, но тенденция к утечке сохраняется. Я переложил подозрение на метод принимающий аргумент *char после того как проверил как отрабатывает логер, если закомментировать logger_backend::getInstance().insert_log(log, strlen(log)); - тогда не будет каждый раз вызываться выделение массива и в теории массив должен остаться такого размера, какой задан при инициализации. Сейчас проведу ещё один эксперимент и сообщу свои наблюдения

Есть вариант не отказываться от преимуществ С++, написав библиотеку логгера, в которой предусмотреть интерфейс для вызова из кода на Си.

Я немного изменил код, заменив log_container = new_lc_ptr; на std::swap(log_container, new_lc_ptr); и log_container[log_str_counter - 1] = new_l_ptr; на std::swap(log_container[log_str_counter - 1], new_l_ptr); В теории это должно чуть обезопасить работу с указателями, также я дополнил вопрос скрином в котором я проверил на наличие утечки через методы класса. Там утечка не наблюдается, но сам по себе она осталась
